# An item with the same key has already been added - SQL Server 2012 Subquery Issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I am writing code within SQL server 2012 to transfer into the query designer of Report Builder 3.0.

My code works perfect within Management studio, and it works within the actualy query designer, but once I press Okay within the query designer, it throws me the error:

```
"Could not update a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct"
```

Under details:

```
"An item with the same key has already been added"
```

This is the code I am using:

```
Select * 
from
(Select distinct srt.Name,
    percentile_disc(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY (sr.price)) OVER(PARTITION BY srt.Name) AS    MedianSpend
    from ServiceReq sr inner join ServiceReqTemplate srt 
    on srt.RecId = sr.SvcReqTmplLink_RecID Where Name like '%') medQuery
    inner join

(select distinct srt.Name,
    cast(sum(sr.price) as int) as AvgCost,cast(sum(sr.cost) as int) as 
    AvgTransCost,cast(avg(sr.TotalTimeSpent) as int) as TotalTimeSpent
    from ServiceReq sr, ServiceReqTemplate srt
    where sr.SvcReqTmplLink_RecID = srt.RecId
    group by srt.Name) avgQuery
    on medQuery.Name LIKE avgQuery.Name
```

I think that the problem is there would be two columns both called "Name" in one table, which is not allowed. I was thinking I could add another column in the same table, and call it "Name_2" and then copy and paste all the data from the "Name" table into "Name_2" and then use it. Would this be the easiest way of successfully implementing this code into Report Builder?

Answer (score -1):

You add `AS Name2` to the 2nd query and then call it after `avgQuery` at the end.